# Access union members of array of unions

Tags: c, arrays, unions

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned i;
    float x;
} f;

f array[12];
```

What do I need to do to address the `union` members in an array like this?  If not possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned i;
    float x;
} f;

f array[12];
```

now you can use by this way :

```
array[index].member=value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, to access the member `x` of the last union in the array, use `array[0].x`

```
printf("%f\n", array[11].x);
```